# Chaining unknown number of AJAX requests

Tags: jquery, jquery-deferred

I'm a bit confused despite the number of posts I've read...

I want to chain `N` AJAX requests where `N >= 1`. `N` depends on the response of the first request and there is a dependency between the first request and the remaining requests. I do not want to freeze the browser.

Since the use-case is a bit complicated I'll try to simplify. Imagine that we have an API that may retrieve all users of an app and the individual address of each user. I want to display all of the addresses. Something like this:

```
function doSomething() {

    var addresses = '';

    $.getJSON('/api/users', function(data) {
        $(data).each(function(id, user) {
            $.getJSON('/api/user/' + user.id + '/address', function(address) {
                addresses += address.displayName + '<br/>';
            });
        });
    });
    // do something with the addresses and display it somewhere
    $("#xxx").append(addresses);
}
```

What is the best way to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a `complete` variable this way:

```
function doSomething() {

    var addresses = '';

    $.getJSON('/api/users', function(data) {
        var complete = 0;
        $(data).each(function(id, user) {
            $.getJSON('/api/user/' + user.id + '/address', function(address) {
                addresses += address.displayName + '<br/>';
                if (++complete !== data.length) { return; }
                // do something with the addresses and display it somewhere
                $("#xxx").append(addresses);
            });
        });
    });
}
```

Also, using promises is another solution:

```
function doSomething() {

    var addresses = '';

    $.getJSON('/api/users', function(data) {
        var $allAjax = [];
        $(data).each(function(id, user) {
            $allAjax.push($.getJSON('/api/user/' + user.id + '/address', function(address) {
                addresses += address.displayName + '<br/>';
            }));
        });
        $.when.apply($, $allAjax).done(function () {
            // do something with the addresses and display it somewhere
            $("#xxx").append(addresses);
        });
    });
}
```

To keep the order of addresses, you should use an array:

```
var addresses = [];
```

Instead of `+= address.displayName + "<br/>"` you will do:

```
addresses[id] = address.displayName;
```

And at the end just override `addresses` variable:

```
addresses = addresses.join("<br/>");
```

Comment: Hm... I was trying to use jQuery.when() :-)

Comment: @lucho Sure, that's another way. I added it to my answer, however, it's not tested.

Comment: Hm, promises look promising. I'll adapt your pattern to match my spaghetti use case and test it. Is it possible that the addresses are shown in the same order as the returned users?

Comment: @lucho Did it work? :-) For sure, just use an array. You already have the `id`. See my edit.

Answer (score 0):

You may find it more useful to refactor the code to provide a `getAddresses()` function that does just that - gets addresses. The function would need to return a promise.

```
function getAddresses() {
    return $.getJSON('/api/users').then(function(data) {
        return $.when.appy(null, data.map(function(user) {
            return $.getJSON('/api/user/' + user.id + '/address');
        })).then(function () {
            //convert the function's arguments to an array of addresses
            return Array.prototype.slice.apply(arguments).map(function(a) {
                return a[0];//crazy but that's the way jQuery's ajax functions deliver their data
            });
        });
    });
}
```

Now, where `getAddresses()` is called, that's where to do something with the addresses :

```
var promiseOfAddresses = getAddresses().then(function(addresses) {
    // do something with the addresses and display it somewhere
    var displayNames = addresses.map(function(address) {
        return address.displayName;
    });
    $("#xxx").append(displayNames.join('<br/>'));
    return addresses;
});
```

The `promiseOfAddresses =` assignment is not strictly necessary to answer the question, but would be useful if you needed to do anything else with the addresses further on in your code.

```
promiseOfAddresses.then(function(addresses) {
    //do something else with the addresses here
});
```